# Code changes not reflected in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, page-refresh

This isn't specifically about an issue I have with any code, but...

I had to make a change in my source code in my local repo on my hard drive. The change was in some Javascript code inside an HTML file. Firefox sees the new code. Chrome sees the new code. But NO VERSION OF IE sees the new code. In each case, the address in the browser's address bar is my IP address.

How do I know IE doesn't see the new source code? Simple: "view source."

Of course, ctrl/F5 is supposed to flush out any Javascript...well, that didn't do it.

I cleared my browser history. I rebooted my computer. I deleted the temporary Internet files and emptied the recycle bin. I flushed the DNS. I saved AND committed my changes. Proxy is disabled. I cleared the caches and cookie via the developer tools as well.

I tried IE in different virtual machines. I had a coworker point IE on his laptop to my source code by having him enter my IP address in the address bar. Now...his laptop HAS NEVER EVEN SEEN THIS CODE BEFORE, but it still was showing the old, unchanged code.

A coworker had to ask me the obvious question: did I save the code? Yup. Code is saved. (And committed.) I confirmed the code was changed by going out of Netbeans and viewing the file in vi through a bash shell.

What else should I be doing??? (The fact that a computer that has never even seen this code before is somehow reflecting older source code blows my mind...)

There were two lines of code that I changed, btw, and one was a comment....something along the lines of:

```
// Detect if the user is using IE9
```

...changed to...

```
// Detect if the user is using IE8/9
```

...and this line:

```
if (my_browser.indexOf('MSIE 9') > -1)
```

...was changed to:

```
if (my_browser.indexOf('MSIE 9') > -1 || my_browser.indexOf('MSIE 8') > -1)
```

Comment: could you share the JavaScript code?

Comment: `a computer that has never even seen this code before` *can't* reflect older source code. It's possible your workspace is in a different location than your root folder and you're viewing the correct workspace in NetBeans and vi, but you're set up so that your IP is the original file (outside the workspace). This happened to me frequently when I started using IDEs; check that the workspace is the same location as the file you're viewing. Then again, because it works in the other two browsers, this can't be the case. Stumped.

Comment: There only one correct thing you can do, do not waste mind on ie, or else did you also cleared netbeans cache located in C:\Users\username\.netbeans\version\var\cache ? are ou able to reproduce the problem ? with a camera ? haha

Comment: There's only one copy of the file in my workspace, though, and my IP points to that one file. Also, since Chrome and Firefox correctly reflect the changed code, that tells me that the IP is set up properly. And also, that would (theoretically?) rule out clearing out the Netbeans cache. (But I'll try it as soon as I get back to work!)

Comment: Clearing the NetBeans cache....did not work. :(

I really think defenestration will fix the problem.

Comment: Well...I think it's down to a problem with IIS. Now FF and Chrome are no longer showing the updated files. IIS is not serving the changes. Yay.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the problem. it's called "I'm a dunce." My intention was to have the page reflect my source code from my hard drive while the data that got pulled would come from our production server. Problem was, I unwittingly configured EVERYTHING to come from the production server...including ExpressionEngine templates, one of which I was modifying. And because the ExpressionEngine template that I was changing was being pulled from production, I wasn't seeing my changes. Basically, I over-configured myself.